# connecting to remote database(MSSqlserver) using applet

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

I am having a problem that I have to insert the data in a table from the applet. since the applet run on the client machine and the database is on the remote machine now when java on client machine looks for the driver `"com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"` then it gives this exception:

`class com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver not found.`

How should I set the classpath of the jar file mssqlserver.jar so that the applet can connect to the remote database?

Comment: where did you have your mysql.jar file?

Comment: I have my mssqlserver.jar file on remote system directory. and can put anywhere on remote system where the database exist,  except that to put on each client machine

Comment: I see you cross-posted this to the Sun forums (http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?threadID=2170035).  Others might help you, but my assistance is withdrawn.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these:
http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/java.815/a64685/samapp5.htm